# is the principal components regression coefficient biased?

Tags: regression, pca, bias, unbiased-estimator

can anyone help me calculate the bias of the principal components regression ? it's clearly different than zero, but i am strugling to find a reference that proves it. and this attached wikipedia page says it's unbiased, which is most likely wrong
[here is the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression)

Comment: anybody ? seems hard i guess